# How to add search form in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

I'm making one custom theme in moodle framework. i want to add search form in header. how can i?

something like `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` in wordpress.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the search form in moodle is available in a block:
[Moodle Docs - Global_Search_set-up](http://docs.moodle.org/21/en/Global_Search_set-up)

You should also watch this:
[How to enable global search in Moodle](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMyXdvBRuho)

If you really want to add the form inside your header, as a workaround you add this code wherever you want in your theme (may be better to implement a renderer displaying this code inside your theme):

```
  echo '<form id="searchquery" method="get" action="'. $CFG->wwwroot .'/search/query.php"><div>';
  echo '<label for="block_search_q">' . get_string('searchmoodle', 'block_search') . '</label>';
  echo '<input id="block_search_q" type="text" name="query_string" />';
  echo '<input type="submit" value="' . s(get_string('go', 'block_search')) . '" />';
  echo '</div></form>';
```

You should look at the search block code for more info:

```
/Moodle/www/blocks/search/block_search.php
```